# laravel 5, which files to put in production after a composer dump autoload

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

recently I added somethings into my composer.json file and did a "composer dump autoload". All work fine on development side.

When I put my updates in production, I had this error :

> [2016-02-17 08:17:47] local.ERROR: exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
>   'Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\f_array_classe()' in
>   /home/dominiquir/ecole/app/Http/Controllers/MatieresEnseigneesController.php:67

when I put my app in production, I put only the "app" folder. But certainly when this file is modified , I must also put in production some other files, but which ones ?

Comment: Which tool do you use for deployment ?

I deploy my whole project into production excepts vendor folder. 
But In production I need to run `composer install` to load the dependency

Comment: I use "filezilla" ! I put all my project the first time. And then for each new release, i put only "app" and "public" folders. Otherwise it take too much time (I have a very very slow connection). But when I modified the composer.json file I must certainly put also some other files, but I do not know which one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An application which uses Composer has to put online

1. All files needed to run the application itself - you should know the location of the files because I suppose you created them
2. all files in the `vendor` folder.

If you don't know exactly point 1, the globally correct answer is: Your entire project folder after you ran `composer install`.

To optimize upload times, you should omit the development dependencies: Run `composer install --no-dev` to remove anything that is not being used for running the application. Development dependencies usually includes test frameworks like PHPUnit or any libraries that are only being used to help developing, like some command line interfaces for the framework being used etc. If your `composer.json` has entries under `require-dev`, that's what gets omitted.

The next step to reduce upload size would be to not upload anything of the application itself that is not relevant, like it's tests. But this depends entirely on how you constructed the application.

I would recommend to write a script that does all the preparations to create an optimized upload. It can be a simple shell script that creates a new, empty folder, then copies all needed files and folders into it, then runs `composer install --no-dev` there, and maybe then again deletes files from the dependency packages that are not needed (like test folders).

You may also run optimizing software for images, CSS and Javascript then. Most of them can be compressed in size without any loss of quality or function.

In the end you get a folder full of files you know have to go online. Just upload the whole folder. Done.

More optimization would be to try using `rsync`, which will compare the files already present at the target with the ones at the source, and only transfer the necessary minimum, but this requires SSH access of some kind, not just FTP.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sven. I have understood. I put all the folder "vendor/composer" in production (8 very light files only). It works fine now ! Merci.